# Prevent function from being invoked from within itself

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an event that is called when a button is clicked

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

However, I want to call my function on text changed of a textbox instead such as

```
this.textbox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

The issue I have is that when I set the text box back to empty in the function itself the function is getting called again

```
this.textbox1 = "";
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: "the function is getting called again" To which **method** do you rely? `button1_Clikc`? I can´t see anything in your code, that would make a second call to it. Please provide more information to your code, as it´s impossible to guess where the second call comes from.

Comment: When I write this.textbox1 = ""; It calls button1_click again as the text has changed

Comment: But why did the `Click`-event occur? You didn´t provide the information on that. Anyway just introduce a boolean in your class indicating if or if not your `button1_Click` was already called.